# Discord Bot crashing: typeerror __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'

Tags: discord.py

I was making a bot just for fun and tested it on my Test Server and everything worked perfect. But when I try to get it into another server it crashes.

I get this in the cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botardo.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.run('token')
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 598, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 579, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 543, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 457, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 421, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 469, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 423, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 663, in parse_guild_create
    guild = self._get_create_guild(data)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 641, in _get_create_guild
    return self._add_guild_from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 255, in _add_guild_from_data
    guild = Guild(data=guild, state=self)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 280, in __init__
    self._from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 391, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 420, in _sync
    self._add_channel(VoiceChannel(guild=self, data=c, state=self._state))
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 504, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 535, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\kakob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 271, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
```

I've seen some other posts about this error, but what most intrigues me is that it works on my Test server but not on any other. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your discord.py version? Also please remove your bot token from your traceback.

Comment: I tried installing discord.py again but it did not work. Apparently the problem was with the Python version, I had 3.8.1 and just upgraded it to 3.8.5. After doing that, I installed discord.py all over again and it worked.

Comment: Glad it's working, you might want regenerate your bot token because your current token will still appear in the post revisions.

Comment: It is an issue tied to dpy version, its fix is 1.4.x plus

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling discord.py should fix the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why reinstalling should fix the problem? Please provide as many details as possible when answering, if you know for a good reason why reinstalling fixes the problem, please edit your answer and include an explanation. The question asker will more likely try your proposed solution if it is clearly justified.